# How many disks for spark_local_dirs?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm looking for a solution to improve my Spark cluster performances, I have read from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hardware-provisioning.html:

> We recommend having 4-8 disks per node

, I have tried both with one and two disks but I have seen that with 2 disks the execution time is doubled. Any explanations about this?

This is my configuration: 1 machine with 140 GB RAM 2 disks and 32 CPU (I know that is an unusual configuration) and on this I have a standalone Spark cluster with 1 Worker.

Comment: What type of disks, e.g. SSD? What is the current performance?